# I want to deny access to a specific branch except for one engineer in mercurial using ACL

Tags: security, mercurial

What I want to do is to allow all developers to create their own feature branches, merge them, etc. but a special branch "Release" should be writable only by one single engineer (or a group). What I tried is:

```
[acl.allow.branches]
release = @release-manager

[acl.deny.branches]
release = *
```

I also want the release manager to be the only one who can add tags in the repo. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that what I wanted is un-doable using the current implementation of MercurialACL, I decided to hack it and support change the way is work to let my usecase work. Also my fork allows you to use globing in branch names like:

```
 release-* = @release-manager
```

this will work for any branch the starts with release-, like "release-1.0"
You can find the code here https://bitbucket.org/cloud9ers/mercurialacl/